# How to Drag/Drop an item from a LIST into an AREA, but keeping its dropped position

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-tsts?file=src/app/shared/components/widgets/components/board/board.component.html) for this problem. That's the closest I could get.

I'm using Material Drag & Drop.
The result I'm looking for is to clone an item from a LIST and put into another list, which is visually an AREA, but that's the "catch", keeping the dropped "coordinates" (x,y) on that area.

**That's my HTML code:**

```
<div class="wid-drawer" 
cdkDropList 
#widgetDrawer="cdkDropList"
cdkDropListSortingDisabled
[cdkDropListData]="widgetsDrawer" 
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[widgetDesktop]">

<widget-container 
    cdkDrag
    *ngFor="let widget of widgetsDrawer;"
    [widget]="widget"></widget-container>
```

```
<widget-container 
    *ngFor="let widget of widgetsOnDesktop; let widgetIndex = index;" 
    cdkDrag
    [widgetIndex]="widgetIndex"
    [widget]="widget"
    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="widget.dragPosition"
    [ngStyle]="{
        'transform':'translate3d('+widget.dragPosition.x+'px,'+widget.dragPosition.y+'px, 0)'
    }"
    [cdkDragData]="widget"
    (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event, widgetIndex)"
    cdkDragBoundary=".wid-desktop"></widget-container>
```

**That's my TS code:**

```
widgetsOnDesktop: Widget[] = [];
widgetsDrawer: Widget[];

//.. more code

copyFromList(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    console.log(event)

  if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {

  copyArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex);

  this.widgetsOnDesktop[event.currentIndex].dragPosition = event.distance;
}
```

}

I'm setting the item position with:

```
this.widgetsOnDesktop[event.currentIndex].dragPosition = event.distance;
```

this attribute dragPosition is an object: {x: number, y, number};
And notice that I used in the widget-container **cdkDragFreeDragPosition**
No success.

Then I proceed in use brute CSS adjusting its transform property. Which gave me a little happy, cause the first drag keep its position. But the instant I touch the item again, the Drag&Drop API identify the "list" and group everything together in a column list.

**I couldn't make it work with the list being a cdkDropList and the area being a simple cdkDrop**

I intended something like [Milanote](https://milanote.com/): https://milanote.com/

[image]

**This is my project now:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you provide some mock, what is your end goal you wanted. As its difficult to understand what you trying to drag and where and whats going wrong.

Comment: @PankajPrakash I edited the question with a Stackblitz. Here it is: shorturl.at/dfkBX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this comes close to what you were after.

Two adjustments:

1. changed widget positioning to `absolute` -- transforming with `position: relative` was repositioning the widgets in an inconsistent manner.
2. had to adjust the `translate` -- I'm no expert with this library but it looks like the nativeElement transform properties are set *relative* to the position of the drawer option the user selects (the NOTE vs COLUMN options in your example). If you add more options you might have to adjust x,y for each depending on where the option is in the drawer space.

Hope this helps and cheers!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-tsts-7uob2y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fcomponents%2Fwidgets%2Fcomponents%2Fboard%2Fboard.component.ts